# How do I clear the Navigation stack?

Tags: c#, android, navigation, xamarin.forms

I have problem for  Navigation in my app. I use xamarin.forms how can clean my navigation stack. No use Pop and push.  Can I see my full navigation stack ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the latest version of Xamarin.Forms you can see your navigation stack using

```
Navigation.NavigationStack
```

therefore you could use a

```
var existingPages = Navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
foreach(var page in existingPages)
{
    Navigation.RemovePage(page);
}
```

This code would have to go into your code behind of a Navigation Page or something that implements INavigation.

More information [Xamarin.Forms.INavigation Members](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.INavigation%2F*)

Comment: Great, I use old version and not have NavigationStack

Comment: @ibrahim you can upgrade your version via nuget. go to references in your project and right click and click manage nuget packages. Then select Updates and install Xamarin.Forms update

Comment: Yes I know, I just wrote the reason for the question. Because with the new version of this question is stupid. thank you

Comment: The NavigationStack becomes empty for some time when I remove one page from it.

Comment: I wish they implement this in Prism.Forms.

Answer (score 12):

This is a function I made to empty the stack and navigate to a specified page. (The use case was the app was de-activated during use and I need to kick the user out)

```
    public async Task PopAllTo(ViewModel vm)
    {
        if (vm == null) return;
        Page page = PreparePage(vm); //replace 'page' with the page you want to reset to
        if (page == null) return;
        _navigation.InsertPageBefore(page, _navigation.NavigationStack.First());
        await _navigation.PopToRootAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 9):

For anyone viewing this in in 2020:

```
await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

or if your using Shell navigation

```
await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

Comment: I am using Shell.. When I try this, it redirects me to root page. But I need to clear the stack and redirect to a specific page.

Comment: Have you tried using GoToAsync() after PopToRootAsync()?  for example: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//animals/monkeys");`

Answer (score 8):

You can try this...

```
    public void ResetNavigationStack()
    {
        if (_navigation != null && _navigation.NavigationStack.Count() > 0)
        {
            var existingPages = _navigation.NavigationStack.ToList();
            foreach (var page in existingPages)
            {
                _navigation.RemovePage(page);
            }
        }
    }
```

and BOOOM!!! that nav stack is cleared brotha!

Or if you wanna reset the modal stack

```
    public async Task<Page> PopAllModals()
    {
        Page root = null;

        if (_navigation.ModalStack.Count() == 0)
            return null;

        for (var i = 0; i <= _navigation.ModalStack.Count(); i++)
        {
            root = await _navigation.PopModalAsync(false);
        }
        return root;
    }
```

And BOOOM! those modals are gone!

Comment: Lovin' the sound effects! :)