# Xamarin forms navigation backpress prevent on logout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating a xamarin forms app.My app flow is *LOGIN-->MAINPAGE*. The Mainpage is a Bottombarpage contains three options. *1.DashBoard, 2.Settings, 3.User* .
 I added a logout icon on Dashboard class toolbar. My problem is whenever user click on logout, screen will navigate to login page. But if user press backbutton it will go to previous mainpage. I want to disable that.

*Iam navigating from loginpage to Main page is like this.*

```
 Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new MainPage(), this);
   await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

**My App.xaml.cs** - *I using a validation for navigation to main page*

```
if (Settings.Generalsettings != string.Empty)
            {

                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            }
            else {
                MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());

            }
```

**My logout button click on Dashboard.cs**

```
   private  void logout_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {

                    Settings.ClearAllData();           
                    Navigation.PushAsync(new Login());               

        }
```

Comment: set MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login()); on logout_Clicked event

Comment: bro the logout button is created on the toolbar of Dashboard. Main page is bottombar

Comment: it will redirect and add into new navigation stack order 'Login page' again

Comment: Why you are using await Navigation.PopAsync(); while navigate from login page to main page. You should use like this  Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());

Comment: bro because i also want to block going back to login pager after login

Comment: Bro i removed navigationbar on login page .It is enabled on mainpage

Comment: removed mean hide or ? You should do like this from app.xaml.cs MainPage = new LoginPage(); // so here you not assigned login page on navigation stack. Once you trigger event on login button action do like this  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());. Here Navigation stack is start from Mainpage

Comment: I hided the navigation page

Comment: ok let me try it bro

Comment: bro changed as you said and changed the navigation from loginpage to Main page as     await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
                            await Navigation.PopAsync();

Comment: But i got error System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.

Comment: see my updated answer. Use NavigationPage navigationRootPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); MainPage = navigationRootPage; on login button action

Comment: bro its not working.   I cannot use MainPage = navigationRootPage;

Comment: what is the error? I hope name casting issues. Please show the error

Comment: If i added MainPage = navigationRootPage;, It say generate field or property. Even if I create the property, navigation not working

Comment: Did you try like this  NavigationPage navigationRootPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); MainPage = navigationRootPage; on login button action

Comment: yes.i tried.....

Comment: Now the issues in when you try to login button event. The above code must work, can you put break point and check, also spelling. If it not work comment those line and writ the code same as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways one if you are using a view model then you can simply navigate like this

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("app:///NavigationPage/Splash");
```

Second is if you are using forms only then you can set the main page with a login page

```
MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

This will clear your back stack and navigate to the particular page.

Comment: I changed, But iam getting error at login page navigation as System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.

Comment: [Clear Backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477139/how-do-i-clear-the-navigation-stack) and navigate to the login page using Navigation.PushAsync(new Login());

Answer (score 1):

Here you pushing a login page again, because the login page is already in navigation stack. So when you hit back button it show the login page.You can do like this  MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
 From App.Xaml.cs page call

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

}

```
  // and when login button pressed from login page do like this
private  void loginButton_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationPage navigationRootPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        navigationRootPage.BarTextColor = Color.White;
        MainPage = navigationRootPage;

    }
```

// when you hit logout button

```
private  void logout_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

                Settings.ClearAllData();           
                MainPage = new LoginPage();             

    }
```

Comment: Bro thanks for you effort. I just cleared the stack as KK said. It working fine now. BTW thanks for your time bro

Comment: Nice, still I din't face this type of issues, but it is useful in feature maybe...  clear navigation stack @K K

Comment: Yes..Thanks bro